Could not find com.github.panpf.bintray-publish:bintray-publish:1.0.0 dependency in Gradle
’m encountering an issue with my Gradle build. I’m trying to include the bintray-publish library with version 1.0.0, but Gradle is unable to resolve it. Here’s what my build.gradle file looks like:
dependencies { implementation 'com.github.panpf.bintray-publish:bintray-publish:1.0.0' }
I’ve tried the following solutions with no success:
Clearing the Gradle cache (./gradlew cleanBuildCache)
Checking the repository URL
Refreshing Gradle dependencies

Can you even publish to Bintray anymore?

As @CommonsWare have asked you cannot use Bintray anymore read more here https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

bintray and jcenter have been shut down. That's why gradle is unable to download the above mentioned dependency.
U can follow your dependency's GitHub website

